# Verifying commitment

Tags: discussion, support

I want to be sure I fulfil my commitment. How do I see what I agreed to and have left to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you commited the popup said this:

> I commit to participate actively in the site for at least three months, especially during the private beta, and to ask or answer at least ten questions.

Also, there's a notification system informing you you have fulfilled your commitment. See these discussions on the grand meta:

- [What does it take for a commitment to count as "fulfilled"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65984/what-does-it-take-for-a-commitment-to-count-as-fulfilled)
- [When is a commitment fulfilled on Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63973/when-is-a-commitment-fulfilled-on-area-51)

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: Given that it's ages ago that I committed to the beta, I have completely forgotten that pledge in Area 51. They should include that in the notification email we all got when the beta launched. It's neat though that you even get informed when you've reached your goal.

Comment: I've added 22 answers so far, and no questions yet. According to the above definition, I should have fulfilled the commitment. Hmm...

Comment: @torbengb maybe it has to come out of private beta first

Comment: nope, that wansn't it. The Area 51 page still says 0% fulfilled. Or perhaps it hasn't been evaluated yet; it's only checked once a day.